# Is there a way to display continuous data on a List View in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-listview

I'm currently doing a project that requires me to continuously display data from a Bluetooth device, in this case, the weight measurements from four different sensors.

I have tried creating a List View using a custom adapter but it would only display the set of inputs once. The data shown on the List View would only update if I exit and re-enter the fragment.

I have been trying to find a way to continuously add in a new set of inputs onto the List View while retaining the previous data on top but I can't seem to find a good reference for it.

[This is an example of what my List View looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RXZI.jpg)

My Code:

**My CustomAdapter**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

import static com.shoeinsoleweight.bluetooth_java_fragment.main_activity.InputValue1;
import static com.shoeinsoleweight.bluetooth_java_fragment.main_activity.InputValue2;
import static com.shoeinsoleweight.bluetooth_java_fragment.main_activity.InputValue3;
import static com.shoeinsoleweight.bluetooth_java_fragment.main_activity.InputValue4;

public class Adapter_inputs extends ArrayAdapter<Model_inputs> {

    private final int resourceLayout;

    public Adapter_inputs(Context context, int resourceLayout, List<Model_inputs> inputsList) {
        super(context, resourceLayout, inputsList);

        this.resourceLayout = resourceLayout;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View v = convertView;

        if(v == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = layoutInflater.inflate(resourceLayout, null);

        }

        Model_inputs inputs = getItem(position);

        if(inputs != null){
            TextView input1TV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.InputValue1);
            TextView input2TV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.InputValue2);
            TextView input3TV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.InputValue3);
            TextView input4TV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.InputValue4);

            if(input1TV != null){
                input1TV.setText("Input Value 1:" + InputValue1);
            }
            if(input2TV != null){
                input2TV.setText("Input Value 2:" + InputValue2);
            }
            if(input3TV != null){
                input3TV.setText("Input Value 3:" + InputValue3);
            }
            if(input4TV != null){
                input4TV.setText("Input Value 4:" + InputValue4);
            }

        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

**My Model**

```
package com.shoeinsoleweight.bluetooth_java_fragment;

public class Model_inputs{

    String Input1;
    String Input2;
    String Input3;
    String Input4;

    public Model_inputs(String Input1, String Input2, String Input3, String Input4){
        this.Input1 = Input1;
        this.Input2 = Input2;
        this.Input3 = Input3;
        this.Input4 = Input4;
    }

    public String getInput1() {
        return Input1;
    }

    public String getInput2() {
        return Input2;
    }

    public String getInput3() {
        return Input3;
    }

    public String getInput4() {
        return Input4;
    }

}
```

**My Fragment**

```
public class history_fragment extends Fragment {

    private View decorView;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_fragment, container, false);
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        List<Model_inputs> inputsList = new ArrayList<>();
        Model_inputs inputs = new Model_inputs("a", "b", "c", "d");
        inputsList.add(inputs);
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.InputValue_LV);
        Adapter_inputs adapter_inputs = new Adapter_inputs(requireActivity(), R.layout.row_inputs, inputsList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter_inputs);

    }
}
```

**XML file for each set of data**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#BFFFFFFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#2B2B2B"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/InputValue1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Input Value 1:"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/InputValue2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Input Value 2:"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/InputValue3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Input Value 3:"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/InputValue4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Input Value 4:"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**XML file for fragment**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/nightsky"
    tools:context=".history_fragment">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_navBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_nav">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/History_Text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fontFamily="casual"
            android:text="@string/history"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/InputValue_LV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="585dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:background="#BFFFFFFF"
            android:backgroundTint="#2B2B2B" />

    </FrameLayout>




    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#00019184"
        app:itemIconTint="#FFFFFF"
        app:itemTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using List user ArrayList in the adapter. Then, when the bluetooth sends the data (this will be a listener which will be capturing the bluetooth data, probably a service or something similar), add the data set to the array list that you are passing to the Adapter and call the onDataSetChanged() function on adapter which is a built-in method to notify the adapter that dataset has been changed. like

```
list.add(new Model_inputs("a", "b", "c", "d"));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here, "new Model_inputs("a", "b", "c", "d")" will be the new data set sent by the bluetooth device.

I would recommend to use RecyclerView instead of ListView, which provides a better way of inflating the views. i.e. it recycles the views upon scrolling.

Comment: I don't really know how to create a listener to capture the Bluetooth data to constantly add a new data set. Are you able to provide any example codes that I can refer to?

Comment: @Albrito The best example is in the official documentation i.e.

[documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth)

Everything is explained straight forward.

Comment: You will find the send and receiving part at the end of the page at:

[sending and receiving data](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#ManageAConnection)